# Fixing errors in ajax login form

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to create a login form for a webpage. I am trying to have the user's login information sent to the server through an ajax request for verification. If the verification is successful, I want to redirect the user to a new page. Otherwise, I want to display an error above the login form. I'm facing two problems with this: the page refreshes after the form is submitted and the errors from the server do not display.

Here is the form I have set up:

```
<div id="errorMsg" action="login.php" class="error" style="width: 120px;"></div><br />

<form id="form" name="loginform" method="POST" style="width: 120px;">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" style="width: 120px;"><br />

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" style="width: 120px;"><br />

    <label for="remember">Remember</label>
    <input id="remember" type="checkbox" name="remember">

    <input value="Login" name="login" type="submit" onClick="return checkStr();">
</form>
```

And here is the javascript code I have that creates the request (I didn't include the sha256 method since it is a bit long):

```
var xmlHttp

function checkStr()
{
var form = document.getElementById('form');
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp==null)
{
    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
    return;
}

if(form.username.value=="" && form.password.value=="")
{
    document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML="Username and Password are required.";
    return false;
}
else if(form.username.value=="")
{
    document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML="Username is required.";
    return false;
}
else if(form.password.value=="")
{
    document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML="Password is required.";
    return false;
}

var username = encodeURIComponent(form.username.value);
var password = encodeURIComponent(sha256(form.password.value));

var parameters = "username="+username+"&password="+password;

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stageChanged2;
xmlHttp.open("POST","login.php",true);
xmlHtpp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.send(parameters);
}

function stateChanged2() 
{ 
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
{ 
response=xmlHttp.responseText;
if(response=='Success!')
{
window.location.href='main.php';
}
else
{
document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
}
}
}


function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
var xmlHttp=null;
try
  {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
catch (e)
  {
  // Internet Explorer
  try
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
  catch (e)
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  }
return xmlHttp;
}
```

Finally, here is the code I am using on the server to handle the login:

```
    if($username = $_POST['username'] && $password = $_POST['password']) 
    {
    if($database->check_password($username, $password) == FALSE)
    {
        echo 'Username/Password was incorrect. You may recover your password and username <a href="' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/recovery.php">here</a>.';
        exit();
    }

    elseif($database->is_banned($username))
    {
        echo 'This account has been banned. If you are unsure as to why, you may inquire by sending an email to admin@torb.com, making sure to include the username.';
        exit();
    }

    elseif($database->is_banned($session->get_ip_address()))
    {
        echo 'This IP Address has been banned. If you are unsure as to why, you may inquire by sending an email to admin@torb.com, making sure to include the IP Address.';
        exit();
    }

    elseif($database->torb->user_approval_denied($username))
    {
        echo 'Your account was not approved. We will contact you if our decision changes.';
        exit();
    }

    elseif( ! $database->user_is_approved($username))
    {
        echo 'Your account has not been approved yet. We will let you know when it has been activated.';
        exit();
    }

    //Code to log user in

    echo "Success!";
    exit();
}
```

How can I fix my code so that it a) shows the errors from the server and B) doesn't reload the page unless the login was successful, in which case it redirects to the main page?

Thank you for reading all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things:

1. In the line `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stageChanged2;`, `stateChanged2` is misspelled as `stageChanged2`.
2. In the line `xmlHtpp.setRequestHeader(...)`, `xmlHttp` is misspelled as `xmlHtpp`.
3. In order to prevent the form from submitting, you need to return `false` in `<form>` tag's `onsubmit` event attribute, not in the submit button's `onclick` event attribute.
4. In conjunction with #3, your `checkStr()` function doesn't return `false` after it makes the AJAX call. Add `return false;` as the last line of that function.

As an unrelated note, I noticed that your `action="login.php"` is mistakenly on the div tag instead of the form tag, unless for some reason that's intentional.

---

Are you using any sort of debugging tool? Two of the problems here are from misspellings. In Firefox, for example, the Error Console showed me these right away.

---

For AJAX, you might want to consider a JavaScript library such as jQuery. It accounts for differences in browsers and simplifies the whole process. These days I rarely see AJAX requests manually coded like you have.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I corrected the spelling mistakes (I feel foolish for missing those) and added the `false`'s in the `checkStr()` function and in `onSubmit`. That resolved the refresh issue. The script still doesn't load the error message from _login.php_, so I'm going to get myself a debugger and try and figure out what's wrong. Which debugger do you recommend I use?

I'll look into jQuery. It seems like a better idea than what I'm currently attempting to do.

Comment: @nickles Loading the error message into `#errorMsg` did work for me, though I removed a lot of your PHP when I tried. Maybe I took out something that would have caused a problem. As for JavaScript debugging, I like using Firefox with the Firebug add-on. It gives you a console and a full JS debugger that allows you to step through the code and to see everything that's defined.

Comment: I installed Firebug and it is probably one of the prettiest debuggers I've used. After stepping through my code, I saw the hash function I was calling was `SHA256` and not `sha256` as I had written. Thanks so much for your help.